# Prusa MK3s+, Prusa PETG 1.75mm filament

Tags: prusa-i3

I encountered a case of pillowing throughout several layers that was very severe, however, I managed to fix it through adjusting the temperatures but I was wondering if anyone could tell me if there any any other cases of this and if they have found a trustworthy way to solve the problem if it occurs repeatedly as it has slowly started to re-appear in different prints after I have rectified the problem, and I haven't altered any of the previous settings I altered to fix it.

[image: same problem as I'm encountering]

I am now encountering this problem again and I really don't know what can cause it, I'm unable to dehydrate my filament anyway due to a lack of means to do so and I used a brand new spool to print this piece that has had pillowing yesterday (July 6th)

Comment: Can you include a pic? "Pillowing" and "bubbling" are very different things the way I normally use the terms, so it would help to distinguish what you mean.

Comment: How many top layers do you use at what thickness per layer?

Comment: it was a 5 layer print as it would be taking some abuse, I'm using it as an insert for draws to keep tools tidy

Answer (score 1):

Without an example photo, it's difficult to be certain, but moisture in a filament spool can cause undesired effects in a print. Even a new-in-the-box, vacuum-sealed-plastic-bag spool can present these effects.

Consider to perform a [dehydration](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=how%20to%20dry%203d%20printer%20filament) on your filament and create another test print.

Comment: The filament is in a controlled environment without possibility of hydration to occur but I do understand where you're coming from. I have now solved the issue and the same spool is printing fine. I appreciate the help

Comment: What was your solution?